# How to know if a user has an active subscription using in_app_purchase in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have this code, which according to the documentation should get the status of a subscription. However, I find an error in this line `QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await _inAppPurchase.queryPastPurchases();`. The issue is that if the user has an active subscription, it should return the text "Active"; otherwise, "Inactive". My code is as follows:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';

class SubscriptionStatusChecker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubscriptionStatusCheckerState createState() => _SubscriptionStatusCheckerState();
}

class _SubscriptionStatusCheckerState extends State<SubscriptionStatusChecker> {
  bool _isSubscriptionActive = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkSubscriptionStatus();
  }


  Future<void> _checkSubscriptionStatus() async {
    try {
      final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;

      QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await _inAppPurchase.queryPastPurchases();

      if (response.error != null) {
        throw response.error!;
      }

      List<PurchaseDetails> purchases = response.pastPurchases;

      for (final PurchaseDetails purchase in purchases) {
        if (purchase.productID == 'sm' && purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
          setState(() {
            _isSubscriptionActive = true;
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Error: $e',
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Subscription Status Checker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Subscription status:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            Text(
              _isSubscriptionActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My expectation is to be able to get the subscription status of a user using in_app_purchase or some other add-on in Flutter.